# how can remove array of object element without slice, splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

I am trying to delete a single object from the below object of arrays. I have tried with slice but sometimes it doesn't work. That's why I want to try different methods.

```
{
  id: "6252de4b27082fd83b94e3f4",
  options: [
    { title: "extra Tomato", price: 2 },
    { title: "ketchup", price: 1 },
    { title: "medium", price: 3 },
  ],
  price: 5.1,
  quantity: 1,
  title: "Carroll Montgomery",
}
```

suppose I want to delete  `medium` object my expected output would be:

```
{
  id: "6252de4b27082fd83b94e3f4",
  options: [
    { title: "extra Tomato", price: 2 },
    { title: "ketchup", price: 1 },
  ],
  price: 5.1,
  quantity: 1,
  title: "Carroll Montgomery",
}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `{ ...myObject, options: myObject.options.filter(innerObj => innerObj.title !== 'medium') }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the `Array.filter` method. Just provide the title you want to delete and you would get the deleted array. Doing so, we don't mutate the original array, instead we create a new one with the value removed.

```js
const obj = {
  id: '6252de4b27082fd83b94e3f4',
  options: [
    { title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2 },
    { title: 'ketchup', price: 1 },
    { title: 'medium', price: 3 },
  ],
  price: 5.1,
  quantity: 1,
  title: 'Carroll Montgomery',
}

obj.options = obj.options.filter((item) => item.title !== 'medium')
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the item you don't want.

```js
const obj = {
  id: '6252de4b27082fd83b94e3f4',
  options: [
    {title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
    {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
    {title: 'medium', price: 3}
  ],
  price: 5.1,
  quantity: 1,
  title: 'Carroll Montgomery'
};

function removeItem(obj, item) {

  // Destructure the options from the object
  const {options, ...rest } = obj;

  // Return a new object with a filtered
  // array of options
  return {
    ...rest,
    options: options.filter(el => {
      return el.title !== item;
    })
  };

}

console.log(removeItem(obj, 'medium'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you should just write custom slice function;

```js
var data = {id: "6252de4b27082fd83b94e3f4",
options: [
{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
{title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
{title: 'medium', price: 3}],
price: 5.1,
quantity: 1,
title: "Carroll Montgomery"};

data["options"] = data.options.filter(function(value, index, arr){ 
    return value.title != "medium";
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrays.filter(....)` to remove item from array

```
obj.options = obj.options.filter((data) => data.title !== 'medium' || data.title !== 'ketchup')
console.log(obj)
```